# Parse GeoQueries closest to a point

Tags: ios, parse-platform, geopoints

My app lets users see people near by. I'm trying to query with GeoQueries to show the closest users from closest to furtherest, the app takes the users current location and searches against the stored parse column 'location' but i get an error saying 'Cannot invoke 'whereKey'' with an argument list of type '(string, nearGeoPoint: Void)'

Anyone know how to fix this?

```html
 // Configure the PFQueryTableView
            self.parseClassName = "User"
            self.textKey = "fullName"
            self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
            self.paginationEnabled = false
            
            
            
        }
        
        // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
        override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery{
            let userGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
                (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            }
            var query = PFQuery(className: "User")
            query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint)
          
            return query
        }
        
        //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
            
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomCell!
            if cell == nil {
                cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
            }
            
            // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
            if let name = object?["fullName"] as? String {
                cell.name.text = name
            }
            if let type = object?["lookingFor"] as? String {
                cell.type.text = type
            }
            if let location = object?["location"] as? String {
                cell.location.text = location
            }
            
            let cover = object?["cover"] as! PFFile
            cover.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            let profile_pic = object?["profile_pic"] as! PFFile
            profile_pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let userGeoPoint is not the users geopoint as you're trying to imply in your code. The geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground function returns void so you're trying to assign a type void where type PFGeoPoint is expected. Since the function is asynchorous, you will have to wait for the callback to determine if you successfully received a PFGeoPoint.

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                  //query ran successfully, extract the geopoint and do whatever
            }
            else{
                  //Error
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but how could I let userGeoPoint be the users current location, could you provide me with the code from above but with it storing the location as userGeoLocation?